# Connectedness of the complement of a compact "small" subset of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

> Let $C$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and suppose that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a finite family of open disks $B_i$ s.t. $C \subset \bigcup_{i} B_i$ and $\sum_i r_i \le \varepsilon$ (where $r_i$ denotes the radius of $B_i$).
>
> **(a)** Suppose $n\ge 2$. Is $\mathbb R^n \setminus C$ connected?
>
> If the answer is yes, then
>
> **(b)** For which $n \ge 2$ is $\mathbb R^n \setminus C$ path-connected? And simply-connected?

Similar questions can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31667/complement-of-a-totally-disconnected-compact-subset-of-the-plane) (and also on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55718/complement-of-a-totally-disconnected-closed-set-in-the-plane), with a beautiful but difficult answer). Anyway, I do not know the answer to the questions. What do you think? Do you have any references? Do you know any elementary proofs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "and totally *bounded*"? If $C$ is compact, then it is necessarily totally bounded according to the usual definition, so maybe you mean something different from this?

Comment: If $C$ is just compact, there is a simple counter-example to a): The unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ is obviously compact, as it is a closed set in $\mathbb R^n$ and bounded, but it clearly divides $\mathbb R^n$ into an inside and outside part.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the problem. Hope now is clear.

Comment: I think you're asking about sets of [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) smaller than 1.